# Stop pagination on last page

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to implement pagination in reactjs, getting the data from JSON and using axios to fetch the data. This is how I'm doing it.

```
class Listing extends Component {
  items = [];
  page = 0;
  itemsPerPage = 4;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }
  getData() {
    axios.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cdlry").then(res => {
      this.items = [...this.items, ...res.data];
      const nextPage = this.state.page + 1;
      this.setState({ page: nextPage });
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

 showPage() {
    const nextItemsIndex = (this.state.page - 2) * this.itemsPerPage;
    return this.items
      .slice(nextItemsIndex, nextItemsIndex + this.itemsPerPage)
      .map((data, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
        //looping data
         </div>
      ));
  }
render() {
    const items = this.showPage();
    return (
      <div id="listing">
        <br />
        <div>{items} </div>
        <button onClick={this.getData}>Load Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, whenever I click on the button it will not stop at the last index or object. It keeps reoccurring.

Shall, I write another function to do `next` the page?
and what approach should I use to go to the `previous` page?
Do I need to use another approach to do the same? My previous approach was to do with `this.setState({})` to iterate through pages.

Comment: Do you want to get all the data at once, and just have the pagination in the browser, or do you want to always do a new request when you press the button?

Comment: All the data at once and then paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the data you get from the request in your component state instead of `this.items`, and increase a state variable `page` every time you press the button.

You want to hide the button if the current page has less items than a page should have, or if the last index is equal to the length of the items array.

**Example**

```js
class Listing extends React.Component {
  itemsPerPage = 4;
  state = {
    items: [],
    page: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cdlry")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(items => {
        this.setState({ items });
      });
  }

  goToNextPage = () => {
    this.setState(({ page }) => ({ page: page + 1}));
  }

  render() {
    const { itemsPerPage } = this;
    const { items, page } = this.state;
    const startIndex = page * itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerPage;
    const pageItems = items.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    const isLastPage = pageItems.length !== itemsPerPage || endIndex === items.length;

    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <div>
          {pageItems.map(data => (
            <div key={data.id}>{data.propertyFullName}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {!isLastPage && <button onClick={this.goToNextPage}>Load Next</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Listing />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works like charm, but why should I go for `this.setState` instead the approach that I used

Comment: @YashKaranke The component will be re-rendered when its state or props are changed, so it's a good idea to put all data the component uses and that might change in the state. Since `items` is an empty array before the network request is finished, and you want to re-render when it is filled, it's a good idea to put it there.